# Command to force a specific typeset engine

Tags: compiling

I have some files that need to be run with LuaLaTeX, but the majority of my documents run fine on PDFLaTeX. I switch between both using my editor, but I would like a simpler approach.

Is there a command that I can put at the beginning of my file in order to force the document to be typeset by LuaLaTex? Something along the lines of

```
\usetypesetter{lualatex}

\begin{document}
(stuff)
\end{document}
```

Comment: You'd have to look at setting up your editor to use one of the following: [arara](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara), [rubber](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/12/building-documents-with-rubber/) or [latexmk](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk).

Comment: Which front-end editor do you use?

Comment: @Werner Some editors can read comment lines for this purpose e.g. TeXShop can do this. But something like `arara` is more portable and versatile, of course.

Comment: You'll still need a document class, though. No compiler is going to like that code without one ;).

Answer (score 6):

If you run either TeXworks or TeXshop as your editor/front-end, inserting the meta instruction

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
```

at the very top of your LaTeX document will assure that the document will be compiled under, you guessed it, LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

If you configure your editor to run `arara` rather than any particular engine or if you use `arara` rather than any particular engine on the command line, then you can set the binary in the document on a case-by-case basis. Moreover, you can also pass document-specific options to the compiler.

For example,

```
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: true, shell: true }
```

means that the file will be compiled with `pdflatex --synctex=1 --shell-escape`.

For files which need `lualatex`, you can then simply use

```
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: true }
```

if you want, say, `lualatex --synctex=1`.

The same can be done for other options and binaries supported by the `rules` which come with Arara, and these rules can be customised and new rules added to meet your individual compilation needs.

For example, here's a rule I added as `.arara/rules/mpost.yaml`:

```yaml
!config
# metapost rule for arara
identifier: mpost
name: metapost
command: <arara> mpost @{action} @{options} "@{file}"
arguments:
- identifier: action
  flag: <arara> -interaction=@{parameters.action}
- identifier: options
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.options}
# vim: set nospell:
```

This allows me to have Arara compile with MetaPost.

See the manual for further details.